# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN - Site going live soon

Tags: nginx, dns, mdns

I cant figure out why I am getting this error. I woke up and tried to enable a LetsEncryp SSL

My A records are pointing to my server. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This error appear when Chrome don't find the way to resolve your domain name.

Is it a new domain ?
Did you tried to resolve the domain from a terminal ?